# How to inflate view inside fragment or how to resume activity from fragment

Tags: layout-inflater

Error :
   01-12 13:53:23.625 19314-19314/com.example.lenovopc.xyz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.lenovopc.xyz, PID: 19314
                                                                          **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity** {com.example.lenovopc.xyz/com.example.lenovopc.xyz.ScanActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.scanlibrary.PolygonView
                                                                              at 
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.scanlibrary.PolygonView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.lenovopc.xyz-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.lenovopc.xyz-2/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

CODE :  *PickImageFragment.java*

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("", "onActivityResult" + resultCode);
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case ScanConstants.START_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE:
                    bitmap = getBitmap(fileUri);
                    break;

                case ScanConstants.PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE:
                    bitmap = getBitmap(data.getData());
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        getActivity().finish();
    }
    if (bitmap != null) {
        postImagePick(bitmap);
    }
}


protected void postImagePick(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Uri uri = Utils.getUri(getActivity(), bitmap);
    bitmap.recycle();
    scanner.onBitmapSelect(uri);
}


private Bitmap getBitmap(Uri selectedimg) throws IOException {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 3;
    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = null;
    fileDescriptor =
            getActivity().getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(selectedimg, "r");
    Bitmap original
            = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(
            fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), null, options);
    return original;
}
```

}

*ScanActivity.java*

```
public void onBitmapSelect(Uri uri) {
    ScanFragment fragment = new ScanFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(ScanConstants.SELECTED_BITMAP, uri);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(ScanFragment.class.toString());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

*ScanFragment.java*

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ***view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scan_fragment_layout, null);***
    init();
    return view;

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. There's only a huge stacktrace....

Comment: when the execution flow jumps from "ScanActivity.java" to onCreateView method(ScanFragment.java), it throws the following error -  
                                                                                               
 EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.lenovopc.xyz, PID: 19314 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.lenovopc.xyz/com.example.lenovopc.xyz.ScanActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0

Comment: Please add all relevant information to your question